# Tensor product in Paul r halmos book

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

[image]

This is the definition of tensor product in the book. But my question is
"*Does for every $z\in \scr U \otimes \scr V$ there exists $x\in \scr U $ , $y\in \scr V$ such that $z = x\otimes y ?$*"

Comment: There is a more inuitive approach to the [tensor product](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf), which actually constructs it, and then shows it satisfies a certain universal property, which is really what you're interested in anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course *no*, the tensor product is the set of finite linear combnation of elements of the form $x \otimes y$. Read further in the book where the author established basis for the tensor product, which means the tensors are linear combinations of the basis elements. Elements of the form $x \otimes y$ are called simple tensors.